# I keep getting a 'while syntax' error on the output of the at job in unix and I have no idea why

Tags: linux, unix, loops, while-loop, ksh

```
#!/usr/dt/bin/dtksh

while getopts w:m: option
do
        case $option in
        w)      wflag=1
                wval="$OPTARG";;
        m)      mflag=1
                mval="$OPTARG";;
        ?)      printf 'BAD\n' $0
                exit 2;;
        esac
done

 if [ ! -z "$wflag" ]; then
printf "W and -w arg is $wval\n"
fi

if [ ! -z "$mflag" ]; then
printf "M and -m arg is $mval\n"
fi

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
printf "Remaining arguments are: $* \n"

at $wval <<ENDMARKER
echo $* >> Search_List
tr " " "\n" <Search_List >Usr_List

while true; do
        if [ -s Usr_List ]; then
        for i in $(cat Usr_List); do
                if finger -m | grep $i; then
                    echo '$i is online' | elm user
                    sed '/$i/d' <Usr_List >tmplist
                    mv tmplist Usr_List
                fi
        done
        else
        break
        fi
done
ENDMARKER
```

Essentially I want to keep searching through until it is empty. Each time an element of the list is found, it is deleted. Once the list is empty quit.

There are no error messages when I first run the command, it only shows up in an email containing the output of the at job.

Thanks in advance for any advice

EDIT: The script uses getopts and takes one argument for -w and one for -m, the w value is set as the time for the at job, the m still has to be used. Any arguments after the one for m are sent to a file called Search_List, Search_List is edited and saved as Usr_List. Then in the while loop, while Usr_List is not empty, the script checks the results of finger -m against the names in Usr_List. If a name is found, it is removed from Usr_List. Once Usr_List is empty, the program should stop.

elm is a way to send an email, so elm user sends an email to user.

The error is :

> while: Expression syntax

Comment: Is the shebang `/usr/dt/bin/dtksh` is what you expect ? Is it ksh ?

Comment: That has worked on every other script I have done, it is a korn shell

Comment: Better explain what are you trying to do in English, and what is `elm`.

Comment: edited with elm explained

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: Done, although it is nothing more than 'while: Expression syntax' in the output email from the at job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the while command and the if command needed to be combined.

```
while [[ -s Usr_List ]]; do
    ......
done
```

Answer (score 0):

at uses /bin/sh by default.

```
at  now <<ENDMARKER

 <code here>

ENDMARKER
```

All of this executes under /bin/sh, which on some systems can be Bourne Shell (Solaris for example).
You need to figure out what /bin/sh is for your system, then modify things accordingly.  Plus, read the gurantees about what is and what is not in your "at" environment.  I think the problem lies there. You have both UNIX and linux tags.  So I cannot give a lot more help than that.

You can enable logging -- the way YOU need it -- of the at code chunk:

```
exec 2&>1 > /tmp/somefile.log
```

Then write debugging messages to stdout or stderr.

Comment: It appears that the at job is executed using /bin/csh

Comment: @user2177896 Indeed, see my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your HEREDOC is being interpolated.  Try quoting the delimiter:

```
at $wval << 'ENDMARKER'
```

Although ( I haven't looked closely) it appears that you want some interpolation.  But you definitely do not want it on the line in which you reference `$i`, so quote that `$` if you do not quote the entire heredoc:

```
 if finger -m | grep \$i; then
```

Comment: Unfortunately `if finger -m | grep \$i; then` seems to change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `-k` option to `at`:

```
...
at -k $wval <<ENDMARKER
...
```

`at` is otherwise defaulting to your login shell which is `csh` or one of its derivatives.